# Documentation for Google Analytics Tracker

Tags: google-analytics, documentation, tracker

I'm using Google Analytic's Tracker for Android, and I'm having trouble finding the documentation of the Tracker's methods online. Particularly, I'd like the documentation for sendEvent().

The Tracker is in com.google.analytics.tracking.android.Tracker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of the SDK are you using? If it's v4 you can find the documentation and an example here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/events